# Windows server 2008 r2 sp1 and Sharepoint 2010: Built in web services doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2010

After fresh install of sharepoint server 2010 on Windows server 2008 r2 sp1 all web services doesn't work. When I try to open for example TokenService if shows me exception:

*Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement
Error: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider*

After googling I found that I need to install hot fix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971493

But I can't install it. It shows: The update is not applicable to your computer. 
In event log: Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2149842967
As I understand sp1 has newer version of this hot fix.
After that I tried to implement my custom transport which implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider.(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/05/13/wcf-and-intermediate-devices.aspx)

After changing transport error has gone but a new one occurs:
*The 'CustomBinding_*'.'http://tempuri.org/' binding for the '*'.'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/' contract is configured with an authentication mode that requires transport level integrity and confidentiality. However the transport cannot provide integrity and confidentiality.*

*After adding " enableUnsecuredResponse="true"" to web config new error:
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[***], cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.*

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with web services configuration in web configs. After installing latest CUs and SPs and copying configs from fresh installation everyting works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem as stated above. The only solution I could find was to remove Central Admin from the problem server and install on another of the web front ends (we have 4 WFEs in our farm). This solved the problem.

I suspect the problem is related to IIS or Group Policy settings on the previous web server but I have no proof other than that SharePoint seems back to normal once Central Admin was moved.